# print has not done using 32 bit OS but work on 64 bit OS for same Android APK

Tags: java, php, android

I have One Query.

I have done restaurant billing android APK which is connected through CPU (Server Machine) using WiFi (IP Address),in this apps i have used  PHP file for connection to MY SQL Database,My problem is when i used  64 bit OS for server machine the time APK is working proper ie it has done all work proper (printing bill & order through Android Device) but when i use 32 bit OS that time printing have not done through Local Device,i have not understand the where is the problem in PHP file or Java file.

if anybody know the solution of that plz help me.
thanks.

in this app i have used :----

```
package="com.example.androidhive"
android:versionCode="2"
android:versionName="2.2" >

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
   android:xlargeScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />

<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="19"
    android:minSdkVersion="8" />
```

Comment: PHP?! where are you using PHP in an android app?

Comment: not directly using PHP,for access the My SQL Database, using http (GET and POST) through URL in AsynTask.